# What is the meaning of 广州产品？

Tags: vocabulary, terminology

微信的研究开发工作开展得很早，2010年底，移动互联网刚起步，腾讯广州产品研发中心就开始考虑相关业务。

Hi all. This is from the Standard Course Book of HSK5, section 12.

What exactly is the meaning of 广州产品？

广州产品研发 = Guangzhou product R&D

It doesn't makes sense to me

提前感谢。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Didn't parse it totally right.

产品研发中心 = PDC (Product Development Center) -or- R&D Center

So 腾讯广州产品研发中心[...] = Tengxun's Guangzhou PDC[...] -or- Tengxun's Guangzhou R&D Center